# intellij jsp editor not recognizing java syntax

Tags: intellij-idea

I am using ultimate IntelliJ 2016.2, JSP editor not able to recognize custom Java classes and so could not navigate to any custom java API from jsp, but the same working from any java files jdk api like String etc is working fine. I tried options like 'Invalidate cache',re-configure projects but having same issue.
[error in jsp page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aXAxu.png)

Comment: Please share the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (sample project folder archive).

Comment: i think you are missing some required library (jars) in the project classpath. please provide screenshot of your project.